# Marshmallow: Adding system-wide custom root certificate

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, root-access, security, system, certificates

On Android 6 if I move my own root CA from

```
/data/misc/user/0/cacerts-added
```

to

```
/system/etc/security/cacerts/
```

it doesn't work anymore.

It is in the system list and active, but my browser says certificate missing. Why?